# Writing a customized looking camera in minSdk 17

Tags: android

I've been working on a customized camera app, it only changes the layout of how the camera is shown but it doesn't change any core feature of the camera.

As I searched, I found these libraries: `hardware.camera2` , `hardware.camera` and `cameraX`.
And my app should work properly on `minSdk` 17. so my question is: is camera api deprecated so I can use camera2 on my app?

As I saw in documents you could only use camera2 with `cameraManager` on API 21 and higher.

Can anyone help me with what library I should use and how I could implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- hardware.camera (also known as Camera1) was deprecated in API level 21.
- hardware.camera2 (also known as Camera2) was introduced in API level 21.
- camerax is part of the Jetpack suite of libraries, and is built on top on Camera2, so is backward compatible to API level 21.

If your app has a minSdk version of 17, you can define a single Camera interface to use in your app, then provide 2 implementations for it using camera1 on API levels below 21, and CameraX/Camera2 on API levels starting at 21. Whether you choose Camera2 or CameraX depends mostly on your camera features. CameraX provides fairly easy to use APIs for preview, image analysis and image capture, and resolves device compatibility issues. You can take a look at its [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) to see whether it meets your app's requirements, if it does, you can get started on it with [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started). Camera2 provides a more fine grained control over the camera, but come with more complexity to handle it, you can take a look at what it provides through its [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary).